# How to switch from ctrl-b render selection to default selection

Tags: rendering, objects, selection-tools

Somehow I switched my default selection with Ctrl+B to a rendering window mode. How do I switch it back to default mode so I can actually select objects again?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please show a picture of some sort so I can understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> to get out of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>